# How to build complex vs code snippet variable transforms?

Tags: json, regex, code-snippets, ebnf, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a code snippet for vs code that takes a given file name, removes a piece of the name and capitalizes the first letter. For example

Input:
example.model.js

Output:
Example

Output im getting:
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*).[model]+$//capitalize//}

I'm able to remove the trailing half of the file name with the following string

```
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.[model]+$/$1/}"
```

I tried to take this a step further with the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)\\.[model]+$/${1:/capitalize/}/}"
```

Based on the documentation i'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? Also are there any tools that could help build these kinds of complex expressions?

Thanks

Comment: It's upcase not capitalize

Comment: my understanding of upcase is that would capitalize everything? That said switching to upcase gives the same issue

Comment: Nope! As shown in the docs, it was capitalizing everything because the whole word was captured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like i was writing the grammer incorrect adding a trailing slash / the correct way is below

${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*).*\.[model]+$/${1:/capitalize}/};"

Answer (score 0):

With this regex `(.*)\\.[model]+$`, `(.*)` captures the whole word.

For eg, it will capture `example` in `example.model.js` and thus, capitalize it as `EXAMPLE`

You need to capture only the first character like so:

```
 "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.).*\\.[model]+$/${1:/capitalize/}/}"
```

Comment: I tried the above in my code snippet and got the following
```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.).*\.[model]+$//capitalize//}
```